# JavaScript Unicode Matching

Tags: javascript, unicode

I am using Node.js to read data from an XML file. But when I try to compare the data from the file with a literal, it is not matching, even though it looks the same:

```
  const parser: xml2js.Parser = new xml2js.Parser();
  const suggestedMatchesXml: any
    = fs.readFileSync(`${inputSuggMatchXmlFile}`, 'utf8');
  parser.parseString(suggestedMatchesXml, (_parseErr: any, result: any) => {
    // console.debug(`result = ${util.inspect(result, false, null)}`);
    suggestedMatchesObjFromXml = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
    // console.debug(`suggestedMatchesObjFromXml BEFORE = ${JSON.stringify(suggestedMatchesObjFromXml)}`);
  });
  const destinations: Array<any> = suggestedMatchesObjFromXml.suggestedmatches.destination;
  let docIdForUrl: string | undefined;
  _.each(destinations, (destination: any) => {
    const { url }: { url: string } = destination;
    if (!destination.docId) {
      console.debug(`processInputSmXmlFile(): url = ${url} ; index = ${_.indexOf(url, 'meetings')}`);
```

Here's the log:

```
processInputSmXmlFile(): url = https://apps.na.collabserv.com/meetings/ ; index = -1
```

I'm not sure how this could happen, unless one of those strings is unicode, and the other isn't.

How can I convert this one way or the other so that the data matches?

Comment: If it is a Unicode issue you could call [.normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) on both strings first? It might also be worth dumping out the strings as sequences of character codes to see if / where the differences are.

Comment: Here.s the weird thing - `normalize()` is failing at runtime, telling me it's not found.

Answer (score 1):

Because I was doing a `JSON.parse()`, `url` was not a string - it was an object. When I did a `_.toString(url)`, and replaced `_.indexOf(url, 'meetings')` with `_.includes(url, 'meetings')` (since Lodash `indexOf()` is only for arrays), now everything is working.